# How can I change the name of user type showed in top right corner in thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

I don't know how to change the name of user type.

Im trying to change the name of user type for my customers, but I can't find how to do it:
[user_type_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSyI5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be changed. There are only 3 types available depending on the authoritiy of the user:

- System Administrator
- Tenant Administrator
- Customer User

Comment: I made a custom group of user with my own roles, they are administrators with less permissions than Tenant Administrator (with default full permission rol), so when I log in as one of those users, the user type name is "client" and it's a bit confusing if I give that to my customer administrator. If this cant be changed I will leave it as it is